# Как корректно проверить является ли символ числом или точкой?

Tags: c++, c

Есть такая функция:

```
 unsigned int f(const std::string& str)
 {
     unsigned int accum = 0;
     for( auto i : str)
     {
        if( '0' <= i && i <= '9' )
            accum = accum*10 + i - '0';
        if( '.' == i )
            break;
     }
 }
```

Корректно ли такое сравнение: `'0' <= *i && *i <= '9'`? Судя по тому что существует функция `bool isdigit( charT ch, const locale& loc );` может быть такая ситуация что `char` содержащий код  символа `1` будет не равен `'1'`. Или такого не может быть?

А как проверить является ли символ точкой или нет?

Comment: `'1'` - это не более чем иная запись кода символа в используемой вами кодировке. Т.е. если считанный вами символ в той же кодировке, что использована в программе - то ваша проверка корректна. Другое дело, если вы читаете, скажем, текст в ASCII и у вас считан 1 байт, а сравнивать вы пытаетесь с широким представлением. Или читаете русский символ в 866 кодировке, а сравниваете с русским символом в своем коде, записанном в 1251 кодировке... Но раз уж вы работаете со строкой типа `char`, то ваше сравнение нормально будет работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Корректно ли такое сравнение: `'0' <= *i && *i <= '9'`?

Эта проверка корректна, стандарты С и С++ гарантирует это (см. ответ @wololo).

Правда не понятно, зачем здесь разыменовывать `i`, но будем считать, что это опечатка.

> может быть такая ситуация что char содержащий код символа 1 будет не равен '1'. Или такого не может быть?

Для C, запись `'1'` и означает «код символа "1"», приведённый к `int`. С точки зрения С++ всё немного сложнее, боюсь наврать в точном определении, но, грубо говоря, это объект встроенного типа char, который при приведении к int должен дать код символа "1" (да поправят меня те, что цитируют стандарт по памяти).

> А как проверить является ли символ точкой или нет?

Вариант в вопросе вполне допустим. `'.' == i`.

Comment: Первая часть - совершенно не верно. Стандарты языков С и С++ однозначно гарантируют, что `'0' < '1' ... < '9'` и что между ними нет других символов. Ситуация правильно описана в ответе @wololo.

Comment: @AnT, честно сказать, плюсовый стандарт поленился посмотреть, но в С'шном этого действительно нет... в любом случае подправил.

Comment: Как это нет??? В стандарте С 5.2.1/3: "...In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous..." Фраза полностью совпадает с аналогичной в стандарте С++.

Comment: мда... что-то я совсем плохой... только что же просматривал внимательно >_<.

Answer (score 3):

Стандарт языка C++ относит символы `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9` к так называемому *базовому множеству исходных символов* (*basic source character set*. Это множество состоит не только из цифр. Полный список в [[lex.charset] / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#1)), которое в свою очередь является подмножеством *базового множества символов выполнения* (*basic execution character set*). А надмножеством базового множества символов выполнения является *множество символов выполнения* (*execution character set*).

Элемент множества исходных символов (а значит и символы `0` — `9`), заключённый в одинарные кавычки без префикса является обычным символьным литералом ([[lex.ccon]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#nt:c-char)):

> *c-char*:
>
> 1) any member of the source character set except the single-quote `’`, backslash `\`, or new-line character
>
> 2) *escape-sequence*
>
> 3) *universal-character-name*

[[lex.ccon] / 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#2):

> A character literal that does not begin with `u8`, `u`, `U`, or `L` is an *ordinary character literal*. **An ordinary character literal that contains a single *c-char* representable in the execution character set has type `char`, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the *c-char* in the execution character set.** An ordinary character literal that contains more than one *c-char* is a *multicharacter literal*. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single *c-char* not representable in the execution character set, is conditionally-supported, has type `int`, and has an implementation-defined value.

Из приведённой выше цитаты следует, что литералы вида `'0'` — `'9'` имеют тип `char` и значение эквивалентное числовому значению, кодирующему эти символы в множестве символов выполнения.

Конкретные числовые значения, которыми кодируются те или иные символы в множестве символов выполнения определяются реализацией. Однако, несколько специальных гарантий всё же есть:

1. Коды символов из базового множества символов выполнения (а значит и коды символов `'0'` — `'9'`) неотрицательны (а с учётом того, что нулевое значение имеет *нулевой символ* (*null character*), получаем что коды символов `'0'` — `'9'` строго положительны), и отличаются друг от друга.
2. В множестве символов выполнения, в списке символов `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` каждый символ после `0` имеет код, который на единицу больше, чем предыдущий.

[[lex.charset] / 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#3):

> The *basic execution character set* and the *basic execution wide-character set* shall each contain all the members of the basic source character set, plus control characters representing alert, backspace, and carriage return, plus a *null character* (respectively, *null wide character*), whose value is 0. For each basic execution character set, the values of the members shall be non-negative and distinct from one another. In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list* of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous. The *execution character set* and the *execution wide-character set* are implementation-defined supersets of the basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set, respectively. The values of the members of the execution character sets and the sets of additional members are locale-specific.

*Список на который ссылается цитата выглядит так: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Таким образом, проверка переменной `i` типа `char` на хранение арабской цифры с помощью кода

```
'0' <= i && i <= '9'
```

корректна.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть специальные функции в стандартной библиотеке:
1) std::isalpha( int ch ) проверяет ли переданный ей символ буквой.
2) std::isdigit( int ch ) соответствено, является ли символ цифрой.

Использование их в вашем коде может выглядеть так:

```
 unsigned int f(const std::string& str)
 {
     unsigned int accum = 0;
     for( auto i : str)
     {
        if( std::isdigit( i ) )
            accum = accum*10 + ( i - '0' );
        if( '.' == i )
            break;
     }
 }
```